# How to parse/extract data from .nfo files

Tags: xml, shell, batch-file, cmd, server

How can I parse/extract data from .nfo files?

I have a lot of .nfo files with server information. I need to collect various information from each .nfo files. E.g., I need to list:

- OS Name
- Processer
- Memory
- Drives and size
- Data types (what types of data is located at the server)

How can I parse this information to, e.g., excel or text file? Since I have >150 .nfo files, I would like not to open each file and copy/past.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: add also an example content.

Comment: I am not sure how to add an example content. I have obtained .nfo file by command: msinfo32 /computer "Server name" /nfo "filename.nfo" /categories + systemsummary

Comment: learn a programming language like Perl or Python that has good text manipulation support.

Comment: @user2266449 really helpful comment...

Comment: it's a generic comment for a generic question. If you'd have added a line of code or make some effort towards actually solving the problem rather then just asking for someone else to do the work for you then I'd have been happy to help you solve the specific problem.

Comment: if you use `/report` instead of `/nfo`, you get a plain text file, which is much easier to parse (I know, too late, as you already have >150 of them, but might be an option for the future)

Comment: [MSInfo32 CLI](https://ss64.com/nt/msinfo32.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you might be looking to parse through the .nfo output from MSINFO32. The below code was what I found to be the most straightforward way to parse through the entire file, and come out with easy to manage lists. This uses ElementTree:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('MSINFO32.nfo')
root = tree.getroot()

for element in root.iter('Data'):
    out = []
    for n in range(len(element)):
        out.append('{0}'.format(element[n].text))
    print(out)
```

The output looks like:

```
['OS Name', 'Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation']
['Version', '10.0.15063 Build 15063']
['Other OS Description ', 'Not Available']
['OS Manufacturer', 'Microsoft Corporation']
['System Name', 'WIN10BLANK']
['System Manufacturer', 'Microsoft Corporation']
['System Model', 'Virtual Machine']
['System Type', 'x64-based PC']
['System SKU', 'Unsupported']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't `Data types` the other things are printed.`msinfo32` prints its reports as unicode xml files so they can be parsed as text files if first they are converted to ascii:

(if all `.nfo` files are in the same directory)

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
::OS Name
::Processor
::Total Physical Memory
::Drive
::Size

set "line1="
set "line2="
for %%X in (*.nfo) do (
    echo+
    echo ---%%X---
    echo+
    type "%%~fX" > "%temp%\%%~nxX"
    rem exit /b 0
    for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=[]" %%# in ("%temp%\%%~nxX") do (
        rem echo %%#
        set "line2=!line1!"
        set "line1=%%#"
        rem echo !line1!
        rem echo !line1! !line2!
        if "!line2!" equ "Size" (
            echo !line2! - !line1!
        )

        if "!line2!" equ "Drive" (
            echo !line2! - !line1!
        )

        if "!line2!" equ "Total Physical Memory" (
            echo !line2! - !line1!
        )

        if "!line2!" equ "OS Name" (
            echo !line2! - !line1!
        )

        if "!line2!" equ "Processor" (
            echo !line2! - !line1!
        )
    )

    del /q /f "%temp%\%%~nxX" >nul 2>&1
)
```

Comment: npocmaka: Thank you very much. I will look into that. In the case of multi drive, e.g., C:, D:, E:,. Then, I would like to printe each drive name with its size. Maybe I can add a while-loop in the 2. for-loop.

Comment: @etyM - I think this will will work with multiple drives.

Comment: npocmaka: I really appreciate your work, thank you. I do get some funny results. Let the serve have following drives: A:, C:, D:, E:, F:, where A: is floppy and E: is cd-rom. Running your script return 2 times E drive, where the first one have 2 sizes. Also there come other lines with size which do not exists. Do you have a hint on why I obtain this?

Comment: In the end, I would like an text (.txt) output with following format: server name, Drive #1 - Size for drive #1, Drive #2 - Size for drive #2, ... (repeating for all drives for that particular server.

Comment: I think the problem is that in the nfo file there are many subjects with the name "drive" and "size". E.g., under storage we have drive and disks - the script take all. I am only interested ind the storage drive letter and sizes.